# Kibana Alternatives

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest, elastic-stack

I am having an issue in kibana. It does not show any results in the Discover tab.

Please [look here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135772/kibana-doesnt-show-any-results-in-discover-tab).

Do we have any Kibana alternatives that the community has used? I searched on the internet and I could find only Head elasticSearch plugin. If nothing works, then I will work on consuming the ElasticSearch JSON feed using .Net and asp.net charts.

Comment: No need for alternatives, we'll make Kibana work, no worries ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only thing I know of would be [Grafana](http://grafana.org/features/#elasticsearch). But that won't support ES until version 2.5. So currently you're going to have to make due with Kibana or manual labor.

**EDIT**

Grafana 2.5 has been [released](http://docs.grafana.org/guides/whats-new-in-v2-5/) and features a ElasticSearch query editor.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are talking about Kibana 4 or 5. When this happens to me it usually means that the time filter is set to a period when there is no data for or documents do not have time stamps or the mapping of time stamp field is not set to 'date'. So the solution is to use Kibana 3 as your discovery panel. Here is a link to a fork that supports aggregations and Elasticsearch 2.x and 5.x.

https://github.com/immunochomik/kibana3

In Kibana 3 you can remove time filter completely so the time histogram will try to show you all the data in the index, also if there are no time stamps you can still look at data in terms panels and documents panels.

Another interesting alternative is [redash](https://redash.io), you can build dashboards combining many sources of data including Elasticsearch. Drawback is that you need to know how to write a query.

Answer (score 2):

Open source options: [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), [Redash](https://redash.io)

If you are open to commercial solutions, [Knowi](https://www.knowi.com) might be an option for more advanced needs (multi-index/multi-database joins, AI etc). See their [ElasticSearch playground](https://www.knowi.com/elasticsearch-analytics).